# Angular js Intellisense Not Working In VS 2015 Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2015

I am creating my first project in express for web 2015. I created a sample app.html file and here is the code. Intellisense is working properly.
[image]

Now I created another js file in controller folder. The intellisense doesn't work here.
[image]

I have 2 questions:

1) Is it supposed to work here ?

2) if yes, why its not working for me ?

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Is it supposed to work here ?

**Ans:** No. Not out of the box, but that can be fixed (see #2)

> 2) if yes, why its not working for me ?

**Ans:** You need to install the AngularJS extension for Visual Studio that  [John Bledsoe](https://twitter.com/jmbledsoe), a member of the Visual Studio community, [created](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jmbledsoe/angularjs-visualstudio-intellisense/master/src/Scripts/angular.intellisense.js).

To do this, download the [angular.intellisense.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jmbledsoe/angularjs-visualstudio-intellisense/master/src/Scripts/angular.intellisense.js) file and place it in the `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\JavaScript\References` folder on your PC.

This extension works the same with any project that uses JavaScript, including Apache Cordova, ASP.NET, LightSwitch, and Windows Store apps, among others.

[image]

Source: [The Visual Studio Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/02/05/using-angularjs-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution but it doesn't work. I am using VS Express 2015 version "14.0.24720.00 update 1". I have installed js file in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\JavaScript\References"  and restarted the vs2015 but still not showing intellisense. When I type "angular", it doesn't give any options in controller folder js file. Do I need add reference to angular.intellisense.js fille?

Comment: I added a reference.js file in  scripts folder (same lever where angular exists) and intellisense is working now. This is the content of reference file:

Answer (score 0):

I followed the previous answer and did following steps on top of it :

Added a reference.js file in  scripts folder (same lever where angular exists) and intellisense is working now. This is the content of reference file:

```
/// <autosync enabled="true" />
/// <reference path="../controllers/sportsStore.js" />
/// <reference path="../ngmodules/angular-resource.js" />
/// <reference path="../ngmodules/angular-route.js" />
/// <reference path="ai.0.15.0-build58334.min.js" />
/// <reference path="angular.js" />
/// <reference path="angular-mocks.js" />
```